# How to compare two excel sheets with same column and want to know the percentage of their similarities

Tags: c#, excel, compare

I have two excel sheets with same column and it has 1000 rows of data.I need to compare those two sheets and want to know the percentage of similarities between two excel sheets.Is there any tool available to do that or Is there any function to do that in C#.Please suggest some solution.Thanks In advance.

Comment: How do you want to calculate "percentage of similarities"?

Answer (score 1):

Can this be done manually?  If so :-

In Excel 2010 you can use the Data --> Remove Duplicates button to help with this kind of thing.

Copy both columns onto a new sheet as 1 column with 2000 rows, click Remove Duplicates and you will get a message along the lines of:

"200 duplicates removed; 1800 unique values remain."

Then you can do a simple formula to get the percentage of similarities.

(1 - (200 / 2000)) * 100 = 90%.